# Request.ServerVariables[LOGON_USER] for PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, apache

In ASP.NET pages using C# syntax, I can get the current user's login name using

```
Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables[LOGON_USER]);
```

Now, we have an Apache server running PHP, but I'd still like to find a way to get our employees' login id.

I looked up the [reserved variables under PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). `REMOTE_USER` looked the closest to what I was after, but

```
echo "REMOTE_USER : " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] . "<br />";
```

The line above returned an empty string when I used that in a web page.

Is this available under PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was blank because this server does not set variables that way.

Instead, it uses the `$_SESSION` to store the username from the database.